# Fluid head loss coefficient for drilled hole cross profiles

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I am attempting to solve the flow rate for a fixture and need to calculate the losses in the fixture that consist of ported holes. Please see picture below. Blue arrow signify air flow and red arrows signify capped holes.
[image: Fixture]

From my mechanical engineering schooling I figured this would be similar to flow in a pipe, however when calculating loses how should I account for the cross profiles for the porting (red arrows)? Essentially, I am trying to figure out the Kl, loss coefficient, variable in Hloss = Kl*(V^2)/2g. For pipes it is normally a corner component and thus I have a table of loss coefficients.

I attempted to research prior to posting this, but I am not 100% sure what this corner profile is even called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first model it using 90deg bend losses and see how that compared to reality, then would adjust those loss factors accordingly... have you checked to see if is laminar or turbulent ?

Comment: I have not solved for Reynolds number yet, am just starting the calculations. I am doing all the calculation in matlab because I am guessing the Qin to prove that Pout=0 at the exit knowing Pin = 15psi I am solving this to get an estimate flow rate of the system. The actual is unknown. @Solar Mike